# Change default auth in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I can't figure out where the input name is passed to using laravel's default auth.

In my RegisterController.php I have

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'fname' => 'required|string|max:35',
        'lname' => 'required|string|max:35',
        'username' => 'required|string|min:4|max:32|unique:users',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:4|confirmed',
    ]);
}

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'fname' => $data['fname'],
        'lname' => $data['lname'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

In my User.php I have

```
protected $fillable = [
    'username', 'password', 'fname', 'lname', 'email',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'username', 'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

Now what do I have to change if I want to change the username field's name to something like acc_username but retaining username column in the database and class?

Meaning that only the input field will be the only one using a different name which would be acc_username instead of username

I've been trying changing every single thing but I still can't figure out which of these actually accepts the form with names and values so I could modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the register.blade:

change: `name="username"`

to

`name="acc_username"`

Within validator change

`'username' => 'required|string|min:4|max:32|unique:users'`

to

`'acc_username' => 'required|string|min:4|max:32|unique:users'`

Within the `create()`

Change:

`'username' => $data['username']`,

to

`'username' => $data['acc_username'],`

Comment: Thank you good sir. I'll have this marked as answered as soon as it's available. Apparently I haven't tried changing the $data['username'] to ['acc_username'] in the create() function

Comment: Within the errors side on the .blade you need to change the `$errors->has('username')` to `('acc_username')` too

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Does that mean that this $errors->has() part refers to the field name? But If I were to access the data, I would still use user()->username?

Comment: Yes the errors will read off of the name= section from the validator which reads the blades `name=`. It would be `Auth::user()->username` but yes it'd still work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem at all. :)